# Using PEP-Proxy to secure my data on Orion Context broker at virtual image

Tags: fiware-orion

I have created an image of Orion Context Broker and created some entities and their attributes, but on accessing in address bar everyone can access that data and modify it. I need to secure that data by pep-proxy.
IP: http://a.b.c.d:8080/v1/contextEntities/

or do I need to use only the global instance for creating new entities.

Please tell me in which files I have to change in order to get it secure.
I have pre-installed orion-pep-proxy on my virtual image (system).

Thanks in advance

Comment: As advice: don't show real IPs in public post at SOF.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look to [the authorization section in the Orion User Manual](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Authorization). There you will find references to the documentation on the different PEP alternatives you have to protect your Orion instance (Wilma and Steelskin implementations at the time being).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will make different entities at the IP or I will change it.
For PeP proxy wilema and steelskin, i have tried both but is it any criteria to use steelskin without keystone, i want to do it with IDm not keystone. As steel skin is for already configured for Orion, i cannot authorized with IDM. And I have to configure it through Wilema which doesn't not have orion configuration. i am stuck to that part only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two main differences between both PEPs: Wilma is supposed to work just with generic HTTP verbs (POST, GET, PUT...), it doesn't support other mappings for actions, that Steelskin support with the use of plugins; and Wilma is supposed to be used with the specific Keystone flavour of the https://github.com/ging/, while Steelskin uses a generic Keystone. Also note that IDM is just a generic acronym to name Identity Management servers (not a particular one), and that Keystone is the IDM currently supported by Fiware (either in its standard distribution or with the Ging modifications).

Comment: Thanks, I cannot edit it twice because of reputation issues. But still can I have the answer please.. i tried everything.

Comment: If you cannot edit your own question, what I suggest is to create a new question.